# Render a form in a modal(bootstrap) and make it available on another controller's view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

It's been a while since I've used Rails and I think I've gotten a little rusty. Is there a way to do this?

I'm trying to make a messaging feature that allows one user type to message another. I want the button to display on the User index page and the user show page. When the button is clicked a modal will popup with a form contained therein.

Currently I've made a Message model with three columns: `user_type1_id`, `user_type2_id` and `message_body`.

Should I make a distinct controller for this new model? Or should I put the logic in the controller of `user_type1` (the `usertype` that will be messaged)?

Any other suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Controllers are there primarily to get data from the database and get it ready for the views. So if you have `user#index` and `user#show` pages, then you should use the `UsersController` for all the logic associated with those views, even though it uses other modals. It really is the "Rails Way". If, however, you were to create a `message#index` page, then you should create the associated `MessagesController`.

Also, there is nothing wrong with creating a partial and sticking in the `messages` view directory (the filename would be, say, `messages/_form.html.erb`). Then, whenever you needed that form (throughout the entire site), all you would need to do was type:

```
<%= render 'messages/form' %>
```

Comment: thanks for the tips. So does that mean I should put a new `message_create` method in the `UsersController` ?

Comment: Well, when you actually create the message (opposed to just showing the form), that `create` method should be in the `MessagesController`. You could have in the `UsersController`, but that would be messy.